# Angular and Navigator.setAppBadge

Tags: angular, web-push, angular15

While building a PWA using Angular 15, and Service Workers, I've hit upon what may be a snag. I'm trying to set the badge count on the app, but conventional (non-Angular) use navigator.setAppBadge(x), which isn't available in Angular.

My solution has been to call "outside" of Angular, using a Script block in my index file, and then calling that by declaring it in my component, and finally using it during the observable of Angular. But it feels a bit like a hack. I'm wondering if there's a better solution? *It works as-is*, and I'm not *hating it*, per se, it's not like I'm modifying the Angular state or anything "from the outside".

The PWA will need to run on the usual range of modern browsers and devices, which is why I'm looking for something a bit more standards-compliant, unless of course this is the way to go.

I've tried googling whether Angular's Navigator supports setAppBadge, but couldn't find anything on this. Maybe my Google-Fu is weak. I even capitulated and asked chatGPT, but that was predictably useless.

Comment: What exactly makes you think that you cannot call `navigator. setAppBadge()` inside your Angular application? I see no problem with that.

Comment: @JSON Derulo I get an error when I try, specifically: Error: src/app/app.component.ts:99:15 - error TS2339: Property 'setAppBadge' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
this.swPush.messages.subscribe(
    messages => {
        const badgeCount = (messages as any).notification?.data?.badgeCount;
        if( badgeCount ) {
            (navigator as any).setAppBadge( badgeCount );
        }
    }
)
```

However, this will only update the count when the app is open.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've got that problem as well (it only updates when the app is open). This is a problem I've yet to solve.

Comment: However, I guess that's another question really, and this does answer what I asked. So I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create my own service worker which first imports the Angular service worker and adds a second listener:

```
// src/my-service-worker.js

// Import angular service worker
importScripts("./ngsw-worker.js");

(() => {
    var MyServiceWorker = class {
        constructor( scope2 ) {
            this.scope = scope2;
            this.scope.addEventListener("push", (event) => this.myOnPush(event));
        }

        myOnPush(event) {
            if (!event.data) {
                return;
            }
            event.waitUntil( this.setBadgeCount(event.data.json()) );
        }

        async setBadgeCount( data ) {
            const badgeCount = data.notification?.data?.badgeCount;
            if (navigator.setAppBadge) {
                if (badgeCount && badgeCount > 0) {
                    await navigator.setAppBadge(badgeCount);
                    console.log( `set badge count to ${badgeCount}` );
                } else {
                    await navigator.clearAppBadge();
                    console.log( `cleared badge count` );
                }
            } else {
                console.log( `badging not supported on this platform` );
            }
        }
    }

    var scope = self;
    new MyServiceWorker( scope );
})();
```

It's basically a copy of the `ngsw-worker.js` file, just with custom support for the `badgeCount` value I send in the notification data:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "The title",
        body: "The body",
        data: {
            badgeCount: 17,
            onActionClick: {
                default: {
                    operation: "navigateLastFocusedOrOpen",
                    url: "/wherever..."
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Remember to register your service worker in `app.module.js`:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('my-service-worker.js', {
    enabled: !isDevMode(),
    // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
    // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
    registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
})
```

... and include `"src/my-service-worker.js"` in the assets section of `angular.json`